# properties of a place viewed by Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, location

I am building a site that helps people to find restaurants on the net .. so i want for every restaurant to show a small Google Map
Now i'm still building my database, in the table restaurant i have id ,name , phone, website, .... 
My question is do i have to add other properities to help me locate the place exactly on Google Maps, what are they?

Please note that this is my first time to work with google maps, and i really dont know what do i need exactly to know about a place to represent it on the map.
Thanks

Comment: mension the platform in which u r developing

Comment: @SoniaJohn i'm just in my first steps on this idea .. not even developing yet, i would like to know , if the place is an object on Google maps api what are its properties eg : location ,name , ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to locate a place. First, you can do it through latitude and longitude. For this you can use [Reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) which can translate the latitude & longitude into an address. You also have the option of using `place_id`, it is used to uniquely identify a place in Google Maps. See [Places IDs](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id). You also have the option of using the address of the place but I do not recommend it; due to the fact that there can be multiple places with the same name.

As for the properties that is available for the place, you may want to look at [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) of [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/). This will return details like `latitude`,`longitude`, `place_id`, `international_phone_number`, `opening_hours`, `permanently_closed`, `price_level`, `reviews` etc.

Hope this will help you. Good luck!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot ... it helps so much !

Answer (score 0):

To locate a place in google map, we need latitude and longitude.

for eg. in android ,to mark a location

```
static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(-31.90, 115.86);
Marker perth = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(PERTH));
```

here -31.90 and 115.86 are that places latitude and longitude respectively. 
I think the logic may b same in all platforms

Comment: Just longitude & latitude are these two enough to locate the place exactly ?

Comment: to just mark a place , we need its latitude and longitude

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it !

Comment: I cannot upvote an answer yet cuz i don't have lot of reputation, and i also am waiting for other answers to compare and mark the right one.